# joomla on ubuntu + XAMPP

Tags: updates, joomla

I use ubuntu14.04 + XAMPP5.6

After a failed update to joomla3.7.5 I get a error message
"500 JHtmlBehavior::polyfill not found. " **when I try to access to the control panel** to log in as administrator.(I've tried in FF & Chrome, the same error)
Can anyone advice/help me to solve the problem??

TIA

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like an Ubuntu problem.  You may find helpful info here:

http://www.itoctopus.com/jhtmlbehavior-polyfill-not-found-fatal-error-on-joomla

Comment: sorry for the wrong place, I'm "new" on stackexchange.

I've read your link but unfortunately that solution doesn't work for me (I'm using PHP5.6 and FF/Chrome, not PHP7 & IE) 

Any other advice?? Thank for your reply:)